# VBA - Searching for column name, deleting column completely

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete multiple columns through the VBA Macro. I have a code that works for the most part, but when I get to Line 5 (or maybe it happens between Line 4 and 5), it selects all the columns to the right of the current column and deletes them instead of the single column I selected.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveeSheet.Rows(1).Find("location", lookat:=xlWhole).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Seleect
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
Selection.Delete
```

For example, I want to delete the column called Location. However, when I get to Line 4-5, it selects Location and all the columns to the right of Location, and then line 5 deletes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim f As Range
Set f = ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Find("location", lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not f Is Nothing then f.EntireColumn.Delete
```

Although that's how the macro recorder tends to write code, you rarely need to select/activate things in VBA